# Dissolving textures to animate blink - What am I doing wrong? (Face animation with shaders)

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to animate a blink using textures and I am using a two image texture connected to a mix colour node and when I move the "fac" slider the textures do not change. I do not know what I have done wrong, any help please? (Keep in mind, I am a beginner so I don't really know that much about Blender)
[image]

Comment: @moonboots Hello, I tried this however I didn't work I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong, Is there any way you could attach a screenshot of how it should look like?

Comment: maybe pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file here (read the instructions): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YZZ2R4gK" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YZZ2R4gK/)

Comment: @moonboots like this? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=d9Jmewkl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/d9Jmewkl/) sorry about this, i'm not really used to blender thanks for the help tho the slider won't change the texture tho?

Comment: ok so I've corrected my answer, I thought you were using a Mix Shader but you are using a MixRGB so the setup I show is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as you're using a *MixRGB*, you can indeed mix the 2 *Image Texture* nodes into the *MixRGB*, then you need to plug the *MixRGB* into a *Diffuse*, then the *Diffuse* into an *Output*:

[image]

*MixRGB* is used to mix 2 colors and/or images, but you need to tell Blender what kind of shader it is supposed to be, between *Diffuse* (which will be affected by light and shadows) and *Emission* (which emits light). In your case I guess you need *Diffuse*.

Another equal solution would be to use the *Mix Shader*, in that case you need this setup, as *Mix Shader* doesn't directly accept images or colors:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! the place where i went wrong was that i wasn't in rendered view i was just in the standard one so that is why it wasn't showing! tysm tho :D

Comment: oh ok, anyway the Diffuse and Output were missing so you wouldn't have been able to see anything

Comment: yeah i just added that in :)